# Saveable background image

Tags: javascript, css

On my site, I use a full size background image. However, I'd like to give the user the ability to right click > Save As on the image. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a CSS background image. You could either have your own element with a low z-index to act as a background image or have a custom context menu, and maybe there's some other way as well

Comment: If you want to encourage that behavior, then give users an express link to 'download this background image.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Browsers will never present that option for a background image.

You would have to have a large element behind the rest of your content that has the image, with everything floated on top of it.

It's not a good idea, and you should avoid doing anything like this.